# Does A Code Database for often used functions exist?

Tags: code-reuse, code-sharing

In the various programming projects I often work on, there are various levels of logic that I always feel have been done 1000 times before by others, but none the less I'm stuck doing them for the 1001st time.

For example, today I am coding tic tac toe, because I couldn't find source that had a reasonable interface.

The other day it was chess.

There are lots of classes like this, that are too specialized to be included in a library, but are none the less frequently written.

I am wondering if there is some kind of code sharing database or community that shares source for functions that might be reusable by others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single function is too small a unit to share and manage; everything basically boils down to copy-paste, which is evil. Separate libraries (in whatever form supported by your environment) represent a much more viable option. Hence, specialized repositories and general-purpose code hosting sites (GitHub, BitBucket, etc) is what you need.

Now, you can raraly find a truly specialized library out there, but you can always start one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you are using. For example, Perl have CPAN: http://search.cpan.org.